# no video over HDMI after re-seating the video card

Tags: windows-7, video, hdmi

I have an HTPC that's been in the same configuration for about a year now. Used daily to watch videos on my HDTV via a DVI-HDMI converter cable. Well today I popped out the video card to trouble-shoot another PC. Then I put it back in and now I get no output on the HDTV over HDMI. The TV is detecting the HDMI cable fine, everything is plugged in but it seems that the PC isn't outputting any signal over that port.

Is there a quick way to fix this? It seems that I need to change the resolution or something, but there's no way to do that remotely that I can see.

Comment: What is your video card make and model?

Comment: MSI 9800GT, purchased about a year ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry all, this issue went away after I blew some air into the PCI slot and re-seated the card. I suspect there was some dust in the slot or the card wasn't fully seated.

Answer (score 0):

First check whether u've plugged in the graphics card properly in ur PCI Express slot, then Log into ur BIOS Console & check whether the Graphics Card is detecting properly and check for all corresponding parameters, whether it is enabled or not. Then check whether the primary display adapter is set to Graphics Card (if not then set it). Save the Settings & Exit BIOS. In the mean time check whether the HDMI Cable is properly plugged in at both the ends & also set the default input mode as HDMI in ur HDTV. Now reset the PC & start Windows in safe mode (press F8 during the boot process to get the option screen to select safe mode), now ,Check whether u get any display.